# How Can I Update Git on MacOS Version 10.15.5?

Tags: git, macos, macos-catalina

I have Git version 2.24.3 on macOS and I don't know how to update it!

Comment: This is not a programming matter. Please ask on Super User or Ask Different.

Answer (score 1):

Download the *latest stable Git release* (latest source version
**2.27.0**) from the [Git website](https://git-scm.com/). *Click* on the downloaded `.dmg` file, then *double-click* the `.pkg` icon to run the installer. This will install the new version of Git over the existing version:

[image]

When Git is installed check in the Terminal, launch the Terminal from /Applications/Utilities and check the version:

```
git --version
```

and the version will displayed.

[Installing and upgrading Git from atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/crucible045/installing-and-upgrading-git-947848144.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using HomeBrew you can use the `brew update && brew upgrade` to update all your programs via the terminal.

You should also check out this article: [How To Upgrade Git](https://medium.com/@katopz/how-to-upgrade-git-ff00ea12be18)